# Why HashMap space gets expanded if all entries got stored in linked fashion under same index

Tags: java, optimization, hashmap

From java [HashMap's source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) it is clear that its space is expanded twice when the space threshold is reached.

I thought about an use case where all 6 elements are stored under same index in linked fashion. The HashMap(size 10) with threshold 7(10*.75) gets expanded when the 7th element arrives. here actually there is no need of expansion since all are saved under one index.

kindly enlighten me

```
        void addEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex)
        {
            Entry<K,V> e = table[bucketIndex];
            table[bucketIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(hash, key, value, e);
            if (size++ >= threshold)
                resize(2 * table.length);
        }

        void resize(int newCapacity)
        {
            Entry[] oldTable = table;
            int oldCapacity = oldTable.length;
            if (oldCapacity == MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
                threshold = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                return;
            }

            Entry[] newTable = new Entry[newCapacity];
            transfer(newTable);
            table = newTable;
            threshold = (int)(newCapacity * loadFactor);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the ready made comment.. Anyways, I will do increase it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say there's no need to resize, since the `HashMap` can hold these entries.

However a `HashMap` ideally should be providing constant access time (`O(1)`). The resizing occurs in order to try and provide this access time. By reorganising the buckets a lookup for a key should ideally reference a bucket with only one value (to avoid iterating through a list of entries).

In the `get()` method you'll find this line:

```
for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
```

The HashMap is using the `indexFor()` method to identify the bucket, and then it will iterate through the buckets to find a matching key. In order to optimise this the iteration should ideally only occur once (you can't avoid the bucket lookup)

This points to hashcodes ideally being equally distributed across the `int` range (2^31-1). You *can* make an objects hashcode constant (e.g. 1), but then you can see the HashMap can't do anything but dump all entries in one bucket, and performance is consequently impacted.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a design decision. Probably based on the fact that maps should be very fast in retrieval and store and if you end up linking so many entries, performance will be affected. Thus, rehashing will probably sparse your items across buckets, instead of leaving them linked in just one bucket.

Answer (score 0):

It is a trade of. All the elements that are in the same bucket while size is small will get scattered while size increases. This increases the performance.